# Error adding new value to LaTeX-math-list with custom function

Tags: errors, emacs, auctex

I am using Auctex with math mode enabled. One of my favorite features is insert `\mathcal` with the key sequence "[backtick] c".  I decided to try and customize the variable `LaTeX-math-list` so I can do something similar for `\mathbb`.  Borrowing the code for the function `LaTeX-math-cal`, I added following code to my .emacs file:

```
(defun my-LaTeX-math-mathbb (char dollar)
  "Insert {\Bbb CHAR} or \mathbb{CHAR} if latex2e is in TeX-style-list.  If DOLLAR is non-nil, put $'s around it."
  (interactive "*c\nP")
  (if dollar (insert "$"))
  (if (member "latex2e" (TeX-style-list))
      (insert "\\mathbb{" (char-to-string char) "}")
    (insert "{\\Bbb " (char-to-string char) "}"))
  (if dollar (insert "$")))

(setq LaTeX-math-list ())
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-math-list '("=" 'my-LaTeX-math-mathbb "" nil))
```

However when I try to type th sequence "[backtick] =" I get the following error message:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (quote my-LaTeX-math-mathbb)
```

When I manually evaluate the expression `(commandp 'my-LaTeX-math-mathbb)` in the scratch buffer, the expression returns true, so I am perplexed as to why I receive the error message.

P.S. I am using `=` for the binding only as a temporary measure during testing because this symbol had no previous definition in math mode.

Comment: Remove the quote before `my-LaTeX-math-mathbb` in the last line `;-)`

Comment: Thanks @giordano!  My lisp skills are still pretty light, so I am still not sure about when I need to quote my variables.  Do you have a recommendation for where I could see why this is so?  My understanding was that the unquoted expression would evaluate to it's variable value, which would be void.  Regardless, I will read a bit and post an answer later explaining the subtlety for future readers.

Comment: The entry you are adding to `LaTeX-math-list` is a quoted list, so you don't need to quote its elements.  See the difference between `(nth 1 '("=" 'my-LaTeX-math-mathbb "" nil))` and `(nth 1 '("=" my-LaTeX-math-mathbb "" nil))`. HTH

Comment: @giordano, the return values of those two expressions definitely explain why the function call was not working.  I think I am bit a clearer, though the return value of `(nth 1 '("=" 'my-LaTeX-math-mathbb "" nil))` is still a bit perplexing to me.